# AppDynamics.Agent doesn't work on .NET MAUI

Tags: android, .net, api, maui, appdynamics

After installing the appdynamics.agent api in MAUI the project does not compile.

Error AMM0000 Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from AndroidManifest.xml:24:18-86 is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory).Suggestion:add'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to element at AndroidManifest.xml:12:3-29:17 to override.

I already tried to put tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory" in of the android manifest, also added xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools" in for tools to work.

Nothing worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Api AppDynamics.Agent doesn't work on MAUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73223793/api-appdynamics-agent-doesnt-work-on-maui)

Comment: please do not post duplicates

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation (https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/22.x/latest/en/end-user-monitoring/mobile-real-user-monitoring) only native (iOS, Android) or hybrid (Xamarin, Cordova-based, React Native, Flutter) mobile applications are currently supported.

Answer (score 0):

Support for .NET 6 and MAUI was added with the latest release (2022.9.0):

https://www.nuget.org/packages/AppDynamics.Agent
https://www.nuget.org/packages/AppDynamics.Agent.Maui